# Accessing local files through an http:// address

Tags: localhost, file-server

I would like to access a folder of mp3 files on my local Windows machine through http:// addresses. For example, typing `http://localhost:9999/songs/test.mp3` into my browser would play test.mp3, which sits in a specified folder on my C: drive. What is the very simplest way to do this?

(Background: a program I'm using wants me to enter the URLs of these files, but assumes they are remote and accessed over http. It doesn't accept URLs of the form `file://C/Users...`. So, I'd like to give these local files addresses that makes them "look" remote.)

Answer (score 4):

WAMP seems a bit overkill just to host some files... Windows comes with its own HTTP server,  IIS. You can install it using "programs and features", "turn windows features on or off"; there you will see "Internet Information Services".

Configuration can be done using the provided graphical tools. An option would be adding a virtual directory to your instance, that points to the directory that holds your files.

Comment: I know this is anecdotal, but WAMP is overkill? Apache and Mysql together wouldn't use the resources IIS does alone, in my experience.

Comment: It is for hosting files - you don't need php and certainly not mysql for that. Apache in itself would of course be more than sufficient, but you'll have to dive into some configuration files. I for one won't mind to do that, but some windows fans just can't bear the thought of having to edit textfiles... Hence my answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you install Apache by itself on windows, you dont need php or mysql....In my experience apache has been the best thing to host your own files.